# Symfony / Doctrine Exception in __toString() in /DoctrineProxies/__CG__/MyEntity.php

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

After releasing a new version of a web application to a production environment the following error is shown:

Fatal error: Method DoctrineProxies__CG__\MyEntity::**toString() must not throw an exception in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php on line 0
E_ERROR Error in file »index.php« at line 0: Method DoctrineProxies__CG**\MyEntity::__toString() must not throw an exception

I am stuck because this error occurs on production only, and I am not allowed to touch the production environment.

What I tried so far:

- Copy db to the test environment for debugging. on the test machine the error does NOT occur.
- Regenerate Doctrine proxies. Makes no difference.

I would love to hear any suggestions. Thanks upfront!

Comment: Can you post toString method here?

Comment: Hi Artur, thank you for replying. It returns the toString from the parent class, I think this is the default option for a Doctrine proxy class. At this moment I do not have access to the code but when I have I will post more details.

Comment: If it's only on production, try to do a `cache:clear --env=prod`